# Generating high symmetry unit cell from lower symmetry primitive cell

Tags: material-science, x-ray-crystallography

I'm trying to create a workflow where one step of the process is taking in a primitive cell of a crystal structure and produce a cell that has the highest possible symmetry (conventinal cell) automatically. For example, if I were to provide the primitive cell of the BCC crystal structure with appropriate basis, I would like to perform transformations that produce the cubic BCC conventional cell. Is there a code or algorithm that can help with this? I have looked at aflow and spglib and it seems they can do the opposite but not what I am looking for.